# Adobe Reader Javascript Open .DOC

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, reader

I just tried to many code from internet to open automatically .doc which are attached in PDF but i get this : "Cannot open type of application/msword"

I tried this:

```
var oDoc = openDataObject("image.doc"); console.println(oDoc.path);
```

I tried to find another function which are specify the type of the document and to can open it in Microsoft Word!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The openDataObject method will throw an exception instead of returning a Doc if any of the following conditions are true:

- The document that this method is being called for does not contain the requested embedded data object.
- ***The data object is not a PDF document.***
- Permissions forbid opening attachments by means of JavaScript.

Instead of openDataObject which tells the viewer to open the file, use exportDataObject with the launch parameter. 0 will prompt the user to save the file, 1 will save the file and launch it.

```
this.exportDataObject({ cName: "image.doc", nLaunch: 1 });
```

Comment: I get same error: "Content cannot be executed application/msword" :(

Comment: Did you see the security warning?

Comment: No is not show me the security warning about to open the DOC i get that only if I press on the button! If I delete the button and I try with the js are not opening. But if I change the launch parameter with 0 is saving great the doc but if i leave 1 is nothing happend and i tried in this way : this.exportDataObject({ cName: "image.doc", nLaunch: 0 });
var oDoc = openDataObject("image.doc");

Comment: You don't need var oDoc = openDataObject("image.doc"); Just export and launch.